# Maven don't download the latest jar from my repository

Tags: maven

I meet an weird issue that Maven don't download the latest jar from my repository. I think maven will check the sha1 file of local jar with the sha1 file on repository, if different, it should download the latest jar. But it don't download in my case, could anyone help on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you deleted your local repository and tried it a gain ?

Comment: Are you using a Repository Manager (like Nexus)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run maven with the -U flag. This forces maven to check for new Versions also on non snapshot dependencies.